# Share state across Google Cloud Functions

Tags: google-cloud-functions

I have a Google Cloud Function that I want to return the same value to all clients calling it. The value is set by another Google Cloud Function. I have this working using Firestore, but I want something that can store the value in memory or push the value change into an event queue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look for in memory and low latency data storage, you can have a look to [memorystore](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/) service. It's based on Redis product and can serve you data in key-value access mode at low latency.

Memorystore is only available with a private IP in your VPC. For this, you can plug a [serverless VPC Connector](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-serverless-vpc-access) to your functions (who write and who read) to allow them to access to your VPC and thus to access to Memorystore service.

Take care to create your functions, your serverless VPC Connector and your Memorystore in the same region to improve the latency.

If it doesn't work, have a look to your firewall rules and allow the Redis traffic port (6379)